# How to select new loaded elements in jQuery without any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, selector

I am working on a jQuery project which a part of page is loaded by choosing different options usign `load()` method. 
I have this line in my application:

```
$('.pe').myFunction();
```

This code must be executed without any event. So I can not use any code like this:
`$(document).on('click','.pe',function(){...});`

It works well on all preloaded elements with `pe` class.But it does not work on new loaded contents which have same class.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Maybe: from **$(document).on('.pe','click',** to **$(document).on('click','.pe',**

Comment: This is more of an angular solution imo..

Comment: I think you should create a custom js event here.

Comment: @gaetanoM It was a mistake in my code. I corrected it. But the problme is not that

Comment: @MohammadSaberi You may test to see if the new elements exist before calling your function. Moreover, you may add an attribute to all new elements in order to distinguish the new ones. I'm sorry, but it's hard to understand **This code must be executed without any event**. Can you be more clear? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. I just put the same code inside the loaded page.

```
// New page which will be loaded with its all contents ...
<script>$('.pe').myFunction();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguably correct way of doing it is using `$(document).on('.pe','click',function(){...});`; however, I did program a fair amount before I discovered that.  So, I know there are a couple of work around.  I'd use a class to mark an item as 'completed' after adding a click event.

If you have any 'hook' to know when the new html is added you can simply call a function that instead of using an interval.

Note regarding the question: you did say no events and this uses no events.

```js
//Simulating ajax loading
setInterval(function () {
  $(document.body).append('<button class="clickable">So clickable!</button><br />');
},1000);

//Your code
setInterval(function () {
  $(".clickable:not(.completed)").click(function () {
    console.log('works!');
  }).addClass("completed");
},10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="clickable">So clickable!</button>
</div>
```